# When to run an async function concurrently?

Tags: c#, concurrency, async-await

The async-await features make it elegant to write non-blocking code. But, while non blocking, the work performed within an async function can still be non-trivial.

When writing async code, I find it natural to write code that follows the pattern 'all the way down the rabbit hole', so to speak, where all methods within the calling tree are marked async and the APIs used are async; but even while non blocking, the executed code can take up a fair amount of the contextual thread's time.

How and when do you decide to run an async-able method concurrently on top of asynchronously? Should one err on having the new Task created higher or lower in the call tree? Are there any best practices for this type of 'optimization'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been using `async` in production for a couple of years. There are a few core "best practices" that I recommend:

1. [Don't block on `async` code](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Use `async` "all the way down". (Corollary: prefer `async Task` to `async void` unless you *have* to use `async void`).
2. Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` wherever possible in your "library" methods.

You've already figured out the "`async` all the way down" part, and you're at the point that `ConfigureAwait(false)` becomes useful.

Say you have an `async` method `A` that calls another `async` method `B`. `A` updates the UI with the results of `B`, but `B` doesn't depend on the UI. So we have:

```
async Task A()
{
  var result = await B();
  myUIElement.Text = result;
}

async Task<string> B()
{
  var rawString = await SomeOtherStuff();
  var result = DoProcessingOnRawString(rawString);
  return result;
}
```

In this example, I would call `B` a "library" method since it doesn't really need to run in the UI context. Right now, `B` *does* run in the UI thread, so `DoProcessingOnRawString` is causing responsiveness issues.

So, add a `ConfigureAwait(false)` to every `await` in `B`:

```
async Task<string> B()
{
  var rawString = await SomeOtherStuff().ConfigureAwait(false);
  var result = DoProcessingOnRawString(rawString);
  return result;
}
```

Now, when `B` resumes after `await`ing `SomeOtherStuff` (assuming it did actually have to `await`), it will resume on a thread pool thread instead of the UI context. When `B` completes, even though it's running on the thread pool, `A` will resume on the UI context.

You can't add `ConfigureAwait(false)` to `A` because `A` depends on the UI context.

You also have the option of explicitly queueing tasks to the thread pool (`await Task.Run(..)`), and you *should* do this if you have particular CPU-intensive functionality. But if your performance is suffering from "thousands of paper cuts", you can use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to offload a lot of the `async` "housekeeping" onto the thread pool.

You may find my [intro post helpful](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) (it goes into more of the "why's"), and the [`async` FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx) also has lots of great references.

Comment: Thank you very kindly, this is a top notch answer and really helps to clarify this issue!

Comment: Async CTP, way back... I think almost 2 years at this point. I've been doing asynchronous programming in general for [over a decade](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/09/an-async-horror-story.html), so I was an early, early adopter of `async`.

Answer (score 0):

Async-await [does not actually use threads in the current .NET process-space](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx#BKMK_Threads).  it is designed for  "blocking" IO and network operations, like database calls, web requests, some file IO.

I cannot perceive what advantage there would be in C# to what you call the rabbit-hole technique.  Doing so only obscures the code and unnecessarily couples your potentially high-cpu code to your IO code.

To answer your question directly, I would only use async-await for the aforementioned IO/network scenarios, **right at the point where you are doing the blocking operations**, and for anything that was CPU bound I would use threading techniques to make the best use of the available CPU cores.  No need to mix the two concerns.